# Passing an Auto_Open macro from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have to pass an Auto_Open macro from one Excel file to about one hundred other Excel files, which are generated automatically from R-script. I really don't know the VBA code.

At first I hoped that opening the file containing the macro and then opening the rest of the files will do the work, but unfortunately it didn't happen and I assume I have to pass the VBA code to all the files.

This macro does a little bit of formatting and limits the values in some cells. I found similar subject but I had problems with modifying VBA code to solve my problem. Is there any way to do simply copy that?

Comment: I would abandon the idea of an Auto_Open and just write a routine that opened the '100 workbooks' on a loop and processed each in turn.

Comment: Ok, thats one of the options but where do I start?

Comment: I would likely start by typing *loop workbooks* into the white text box in the upper right of this page and hitting [Enter].

Comment: Woah, It may even work

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a template containing the "Auto_Open" Macro and use this template to generate the hundreds of files with the "R-Script"